# Dynamically changing back button image

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have the below code to set the back button image on a navigation bar.
The navigation controller is on a tab bar controller.
The problem is, when I push the view the first time it shows the correct button image. If I go into my settings (on another tab) and change which button should be displayed then go back to tab 1 and push the same view again, the old back button is still displayed even though the correct code is called in the if statement!
Now if I pop the view and push it back on again, the correct button is now displayed.

I dont understand why the button isn't changed even though the code is called to change it, but after the first time it changes fine! The ViewController's viewDidLoad method is called each time, so its not like anything should persist.

```
if ([[DataSingleton sharedSingleton] isBlue]) {
    NSLog(@"isBlue");
    // Set toolBar and button colours
    UIImage *navBarImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PortraitNavBarBlue"];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:navBarImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    UIImage *barButton = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"backBlue"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 14, 0, 7)];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:barButton forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
} else {
    NSLog(@"notBlue");
    // Set toolBar and button colours
    UIImage *navBarImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PortraitNavBar"];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:navBarImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    UIImage *barButton = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"back"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 14, 0, 7)];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:barButton forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

I think the bar colour might be changing fine because I call self.navigationController.navigationBar whereas for the back button i'm calling [UIBarButtonItem appearance] which is a global setting.
Is there a way I can reference the back button directly?

Comment: viewDidLoad is always called when the viewController is popped ? It seems  to be not good.

Comment: The view is realloced when popped. This is normal behaviour that results in viewDidLoad being called when pushed again.

Comment: `RootVC -> push ChildVC -> pop ChildVC` should not always call viewDidLoad of RootVC, where do you have this `if` switch anyway ?

Comment: Sorry, the viewDidLoad with this code is in the ChildVC. It changes the navbar image fine each time, but not the back button.

Comment: I don't have much experience working with `appearance`, but that looks very much like `viewDidLoad` of the pushed controller is not the place  to customize `appearance`, did you try to set it at settings viewcontroller, or `RootVC`, or at viewcontrollers orchestrator if you have any - *before `ChildVC` is pushed* ?

Comment: I tried in the RootVC and it had the same affect. The back button only changed on the 2nd push.

Comment: I think this could be a bug, because when the back button should be a different colour, if I press and hold on it, then drag my finger off, the button changes colour to what it should be!